# Which statistical test(s) should i run? (really confused) 2x3 repeated measures - Mixed ANCOVA?

Tags: anova, mixed-model, ancova

at the moment i'm examining the effect of an intervention on health (GHQ) scores among carers of people with dissabilities, but i'm stuck with the tests I should run..

Its a **2 x 3** (quasi experimental) design with repeated measures. Between subjects **Group** (experimental and control) and Within **Time** (T1: 1 week before, T2: 1 week after and T3: 3 weeks after intervention).

My hypotheses are:

1. Carers in the experimental group indicate better health over time (after the intervention).
2. Carers in the control group indicate no change of health scores over time (after intervention).
3. Carers in the experimental group indicate better health over time compared to carers in the control group.

However, based on descriptive statistics, *the groups differ significantly at baseline in GHQ scores (and age aswell*). So I have to control for those variables, right? But i'm really stuck in choosing the right statistic tests...

I read about repeated measures ANCOVA here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21476717

So I thought about a mixed repeated measures ANCOVA (controlling for age), and if there is a significant interaction of Group X Time, the effect of time depends on group. According to the IBM site, I dont have to bother about the differences at baseline of GHC using this technique?. Then I should run simple effects in order to examine simple main effects.

But i'm totally lost if I can test each hypothese with just this ANCOVA, or only hypothese 3.

If only hypothese 3, then for 1 and 2 I have to conduct separate ANCOVA's for post scores by group while controlling for pre score?

Sorry if my question is quite stupid, but i'm a bit lost and really dont see it anymore atm...

Answer (score 0):

Please, could someone help me? A.t.m. I have conducted 2 one-way between groups ANCOVA's for health scores on T2 and T3, while controlling for scores on T1. These results for Hypothesis 1 and 2.

And for 3, a mixed ANOVA with time and group, to indicate whether there is an interaction effect.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question. It is re-emphasis of the question.

Comment: Yes, sorry I am new to this platform. Noticed that after I placed it, but can't  delete it...

Comment: You are always be able to delete a question or an answer.